# How to dosconnect/close a stucked HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, io, httpurlconnection, deadlock

Please consider the case:

- HttpURLConnection was open but does not receive any data from socket (e.g. due to firewall configuration).
- Another thread wants to disconnect that connection due to timeout but gets blocked in ChunkedInputStream.close():

  ```
  "thread-2" - Thread t@333
     java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.close(ChunkedInputStream.java:746)
    - waiting to lock <2be20ded> (a sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream)
  owned by "thread-1" t@385
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3409)
    at
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.disconnect(HttpURLConnection.java:2824)
  ...

  "thread-1" - Thread t@385
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <c9077bc> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at
  sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:552)
    at
  sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
    - locked <2be20ded> (a sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at
  sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3336)
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:207)
    at
  org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown
  Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
    at
  org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
  Source)
    at
  org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
  Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
  Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at
  com.lmax.api.internal.protocol.EventStreamHandler.parseEventStream(EventStreamHandler.java:45)
  ...
     Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <4dbb989f> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
  ```

Is there any way to avoid the deadlock?
The only workaround I found is to specify `readTimeout` and `connectTimeout` on `java.net.URLConnection`.

Any ideas?

SUT: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_102

Comment: And what's wrong with setting the `readTimeout` and `connectTimeout`?

Comment: It's nothing wrong unless It's third-party code